# TL-SG108E VLAN issue

Tags: networking, router, lan, switch, vlan

I created some vlans with my managed switch using the option MTU VLAN.
The only problem is that I have devices connected directly to the switch which are separated from each other, but they're not separated from the ones connected to other ports of the router. How can I totally separate devices from the rest of the LAN?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd read the manual it says

> MTU VLAN (Multi-Tenant Unit VLAN) defines an uplink port which will
> build up several VLANs with each of the other ports. Each VLAN
> contains two ports, the uplink port and one of the other ports in the
> switch, so the device connected to the uplink port can communicate
> with the device connected to any other port, but devices connected to
> other ports cannot communicate with each other.

So, the uplink port can talk to all VLAN ports and all the other VLAN ports can only talk to the uplink port. This is also called private VLAN or port isolation sometimes. If that's not what you want, port-based VLANs may be:

> VLANs are divided based on ports. In port based VLAN mode, each port
> can only be added to one VLAN.

Essentially, each VLAN acts as a virtual switch.

https://static.tp-link.com/2020/202011/20201102/1910012910_Easy%20Smart%20Switch_UG.pdf

Comment: I have the problem with devices outside the switch, maybe because they're considered as part of the uplink port?

Comment: Please re-read my answer. An MTU VLAN isn't what you want, you want a port-based VLAN.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I created a port-based VLAN but I can still talk to devices outside the switch that are in the LAN

Comment: Please add a diagram to your question how you've connected things and include the config details of the switch.